# ansible filters or plugins to search for IP addresses in a text file

Tags: plugins, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Is there a way to search for an IP address inside a body of random text without using the regex filter?

I have been looking at the `Ipaddr` and related filters but that appears to validate if it is an IP or not.

I'm open to any method besides regex unless regex is the only method.  I'm ok with regex and I have the pattern to search for an IP I was just wondering if there is a plugin or a filter that would do that.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in ansible that extracts things from a sea of text; but you can get pretty close by just grabbing _any_ contiguous string of `[0-9.:]{7,39}` and then feeding those results through the test